# Python Poppler install issues

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, poppler

Trying to install **python-poppler-qt4** on Windows (8.1) but i've been having issues building/installing it 
(*error fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QMetaType' : No such file or directory. #include QMetaType*)

Before this error I had a missing poppler-qt4.dll issue. After locating and installing the dll I get the error above

It's pretty annoying how I cant install this package like any other .. suggestions? Really need to use poppler for PDF rendering.

Answer (score 0):

In `C:\poppler-0.24.5\include\src` replace it `C:\poppler-0.24.5\include\qt4\src`

Answer (score -1):

All is taken care of using the following.
[My POC code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264425/python-pdf-to-image-rendering)

- [PGI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgi/)
- cairo
- etc